# Guardar fecha actual en variables dentro de un struct

Tags: c

Me gustaría saber como puedo sacar la fecha actual y guardarla dentro de un struct. De momento tengo hecho esto pero el resultado no es correcto. El año se me guarda en cada variable. Me seria de ayuda si alguien me pudiera solucionar esta duda. Muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Inmueble {

    char codigo[10];
    char direccion[40];
    char localidad[20];
    char ciudad[20];
    int codigo_postal[4];
    float precio_tasacion[10];
    float precio_venta[10];
    float oferta_aceptada[10];
    float beneficio_minimo[10];
    char dia_alta[1];
    char mes_alta[1];
    char anio_alta[1];

}tRegInmueble;

int main()
{
    tRegInmueble inmueble;

    time_t t;
    struct tm *st ;
    char *ch ;
    time(&t);

    st = localtime(&t);
         sprintf(inmueble.dia_alta ,"%d/", st-> tm_mday);
         sprintf(inmueble.mes_alta, "%d/", st-> tm_mon + 1);
         sprintf(inmueble.anio_alta, "%d", st-> tm_year + 1900);

    printf("%s/%s/%s", inmueble.dia_alta, inmueble.mes_alta, inmueble.anio_alta);
}
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

> Me gustaría saber como puedo sacar la fecha actual

Eso ya lo sabes hacer, de hecho ya lo haces en tu código:

```
time_t t;
time(&t); // Leer fecha actual.
```

> y guardarla dentro de un struct

Sencillo, haz que forme parte de dicho `struct`:

```
typedef struct Inmueble {
    char codigo[10];
    char direccion[40];
    char localidad[20];
    char ciudad[20];
    int codigo_postal[4];
    float precio_tasacion[10];
    float precio_venta[10];
    float oferta_aceptada[10];
    float beneficio_minimo[10];
    time_t fecha; // Fecha del registro
}tRegInmueble;
```

Sencillo ¿verdad?

```
int main()
{
    tRegInmueble inmueble;

    char *ch ;
    time(&inmueble.fecha);

    struct tm *st = localtime(&inmueble.fecha);
    printf("%d/%d/%s", st->tm_mday, st->tm_mon + 1, st->tm_year + 1900);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad. Soy relativamente nuevo programando y me es de mucha ayuda.